# CanvasAuthorize and VerificationException

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm executing this piece of code:

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();

        dynamic result = fb.Get("me");

        ViewData["Firstname"] = result.first_name;
        ViewData["Lastname"] = result.last_name;


        return View();
    }
```

And I get the following exception.. Any idea?

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Operation could destabilize the runtime. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   SimpleJson.SimpleJson.ParseValue(Char[] json, Int32& index, Boolean& success) +107
   SimpleJson.SimpleJson.TryDeserializeObject(String json, Object& object) +212
   SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(String json) +84
   Facebook.SimpleJsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(String json) +112
   Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest.TryParse(String secret, String signedRequestValue, Int32 maxAge, Double currentTime, Boolean throws) +3096
   Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(String secret, String signedRequestValue) +445
   Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest.GetSignedRequest(String appSecret, HttpContextBase httpContext) +931
   Facebook.FacebookSession.GetSession(String appId, String appSecret, HttpContextBase httpContext, FacebookSignedRequest signedRequest) +1031
   Facebook.FacebookSession.GetSession(String appId, String appSecret, HttpContextBase httpContext) +128
   Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.get_Session() +317
   Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.IsAuthenticated() +136
   Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.IsAuthorized(String[] permissions) +186
   Facebook.Web.Mvc.CanvasAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext, IFacebookApplication settings) +572
   Facebook.Web.Mvc.FacebookAuthorizeAttributeBase.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +149
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +831
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +142
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +61
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +110
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +690
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +194

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1  I

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    CanvasAuthorizer auth = new CanvasAuthorizer();
    FacebookWebClient client = new FacebookWebClient(auth.FacebookWebRequest.Session.AccessToken);

    dynamic result = client.Get("me");

    ViewData["Firstname"] = result.first_name;
    ViewData["Lastname"] = result.last_name;


    return View();
}
```